Email data not appearing on Email Analytics
I recently activated a new version of a previously functional journey, retaining all email contents from version 4. However, one of the Email Activities is not triggering as expected. The email analytics screen is not providing useful information; it appears as though no clients have reached that point, yet there is clear evidence that at least one has.

The email does not have any fancy code or command and all other emails are working corectly.
How can I solve this problem?

You should check your contact details on this email step, as the single person who reached it might have been suppressed due to various reasons - resulting in the email not being sent from SFMC.
You can find the specifics for that contact by clicking the icon with the contact count (8 in this case) just below the activity:

This will show more details about these contacts:

If you click "View Contact Details" you will see details about what happened to your contact entering this step.

The email is marked as a success in thes screen, and the client was an internal one that we are sure that is not blocked, since they recieved emails from others journeys

Did you check the above details, @GabrielZanotelli?

Yes. It had 1 success and 0 errors

Did the recipient check the spam folder?

Yes. But there is no information o Marketing Cloud that suggest that the email was sent, even thought its said that the it was sent successfully inside the journey
